# Flutter: how can I do two different things depending on state of an animated icon?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
          IconButton(
              icon: AnimatedIcon(
                icon: AnimatedIcons.menu_close,
                progress: _animationController,
                semanticLabel: 'Pause',
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                subscription.pause();
                setState(() {
                  expanded ? _animationController.forward() : _animationController.reverse();
                  expanded = !expanded;
                });
              }),
```

I'd like to do subscription.pause(); when not expanded onpress, and subscription.resume(); when expanded onpress. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 IconButton(
          icon: AnimatedIcon(
            icon: AnimatedIcons.menu_close,
            progress: _animationController,
            semanticLabel: 'Pause',
          ),
          onPressed: () {
              expanded ?subscription.resume():subscription.pause();
            setState(() {
              expanded ? _animationController.forward() : 
             _animationController.reverse();
              expanded = !expanded;});

                    
          }),
```

Comment: I'm a tad lost.. is it possible to pass two functions the same way? one being a true/false like so:                   isStopped = false;  
                  sec5Timer();        // and the opposite for reverse, isStopped would be true but sec5Timer would have to fire as well